Efficient proof that a number is NOT a Zumkeller number?
The subset sum problem is known to be NP-complete , so in general there is no efficient method to decide it , in particular to prove a negative result.
This problem arises in the problem to decide whether a positive integer $N$ is a Zumkeller-number , this is the case if there are distinct divisors of $N$ summing up to $\frac{\sigma(N)}{2}$ , where $\sigma(N)$ is the sum of the divisors of $N$ including $1$ and $N$. A necesasary condition is that $N$ is perfect or abundant , but many abundant numbers are no Zumkeller-numbers.

Can we prove a negative result efficiently in this special case ? Is this special subset-sum problem easier and can we hope that the Zumkeller-decision is not NP-complete ? We can assume that the prime factorization of $N$ is known.

I am only aware of some sufficient conditions for a number to be a Zumkeller-number. The only routine I found was a Rosetta-Code in PARI/GP which is however both very slow and massively space-consuming.

This is a specific case of subset sum called the partition problem, which is easier in practice, but still NP-complete
